# Property related to the order of a group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$. Assume that $a$ has order 7 and the $a^3b=ba^3$. Prove that $ab=ba$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=a^3$, since $a$ has order $7$, you can check that $a=A^5$.

Now, if $A$ and $b$ commute, then $b$ commute with any power of $A$, including $a$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There are two steps. Firstly, prove that if $xy=yx$ then $x^iy=yx^i$ for all $i$ ($x$ and $y$ are elements in an arbitrary group). Secondly, find an $i$ such that $a^{3i}=a$.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Because I answered a possible homework question with a ***hint***?

Comment: I did not down vote.

Comment: @Jean-Francois I was presuming it wasn't you :-)

Comment: Someone seems to be playing a game here :)

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ has order $7$, then $a^3$ is a generator of $\langle a \rangle$ since $3$ and $7$ are coprime. So if also $a^3 \in C_G(b)$, it follows that $\langle a \rangle = \langle a^3 \rangle \leq C_G(b)$.

Comment: what is cg(b) ?

Comment: @Jean-Francois It is the *centraliser* of $b$ in $G$, that is, the elements of $G$ which commute with $b$. So $C_G(b)=\{g\in G; bg=gb\}$.